# Speed up lambda on selected columns with same values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am currently running a lambda on multiple columns of a pandas dataframe only if another column is True, otherwise the column stays the same.

`df[“a”] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x[“b”], x[“c”]) if x[“d”] == True, else x[“a”])`

The function in the lambda is an api call and takes quite long. Thus this lambda takes quite long (as the dataframe is also large). The values of the inputs of the lambda (column b and column c) are often the same for the rows.

Is there a way to make this faster and not have the lambda do an api call everytime, but only when it sees a new value of b or c?

Comment: "Is there a way to make this faster and not have the lambda do an api call everytime, but only when it sees a new value of b or c?" add caching

Answer (score 0):

For the API part, you can keep a dictionary of results, which stores the pairs of `x['b'], x['c']` as keys and the result of `f(x['b'], x['c'])` as values, so you could skip the function call if the call with `x['b']` & `x['c']` has already been made.

```
cache = dict()
def fun(x):
    b, c = x['b'], x['c']
    if not (b,c) in cache:
        cache[(b,c)] = f(b,c)
    return cache[(b,c)]
```

And you can use this function + Ian's solution instead of lambda + apply.

```
df['a'] = np.where(df['d'] == True, fun(df['b'],df['c']), df['a'])
```

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, use `functools.cache` or `functools.lru_cache`

Comment: And you *can't* use this function in a vectorized way....